# Rails filtering array of objects by attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I perform a query to the db and I have a complete array of objects:

```
@attachments = Job.find(1).attachments
```

Now that I have an array of objects I don't want to perform another db query, but I would like to filter the array based on the `Attachment` object's `file_type` so that I can have a list of `attachments` where the file type is `'logo'` and then another list of `attachments` where the file type is `'image'`

Something like this:

```
@logos  = @attachments.where("file_type = ?", 'logo')
@images = @attachments.where("file_type = ?", 'image')
```

But in memory instead of a db query.

Comment: Seems like a good use case for `partition` - [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069993/rails-filtering-array-of-objects-by-attribute-value/56565339#answer-56565339).

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Try :

This is fine :

```
@logos = @attachments.select { |attachment| attachment.file_type == 'logo' }
@images = @attachments.select { |attachment| attachment.file_type == 'image' }
```

but for performance wise you don't need to iterate @attachments twice :

```
@logos , @images = [], []
@attachments.each do |attachment|
  @logos << attachment if attachment.file_type == 'logo'
  @images << attachment if attachment.file_type == 'image'
end
```

Comment: As @Vik's solution is pretty much ideal, I'll just add that in binary cases, you could use a 'partition' function to make things sweet.  http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition

Comment: Thanks @Vlad, thats cool, but it support only if we need to collect only two things from object.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "binary"  :).  In the question, there was apparently a choice of logo or image, so I added this for completeness.

Answer (score 11):

If your attachments are

```
@attachments = Job.find(1).attachments
```

This will be array of attachment objects

Use select method to filter based on file_type.

```
@logos = @attachments.select { |attachment| attachment.file_type == 'logo' }
@images = @attachments.select { |attachment| attachment.file_type == 'image' }
```

This will not trigger any db query.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried eager loading?

```
@attachments = Job.includes(:attachments).find(1).attachments
```

Comment: Sorry I am not being clear: how do I filter by an object attribute's value without looping through the array?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want less db query, especially, once a query such as `@attachments = Job.first.attachments` executed, you want to loop the `@attachments` meanwhile you don't want any more db queries.   is this what you want to do?

Comment: I do a db query and receive an array of objects. I then want to create two separate lists from that one array by filtering the objects based on the value of their attributes (See original post) - cheers

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions of ruby, you can use

```
@logos = @attachments.filter { |attachment| attachment.file_type == 'logo' }
```

Reference: https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

I'd go about this slightly differently. Structure your query to retrieve only what you need and split from there.

So make your query the following:

```
#                                vv or Job.find(1) vv
attachments = Attachment.where(job_id: @job.id, file_type: ["logo", "image"])
# or 
Job.includes(:attachments).where(id: your_job_id, attachments: { file_type: ["logo", "image"] })
```

And then partition the data:

```
@logos, @images = attachments.partition { |attachment| attachment.file_type == "logo" }
```

That will get the data you're after in a neat and efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using where

```
Job.includes(:attachments).where(file_type: ["logo", "image"])
```