# Avoiding db hits in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, instance-variables

When I assign a database find to an instance variable in Rails, why do future requests to that variable also hit the database?  Can this be avoided?

For example, I have 3 models: User, Resource, Opinion, with has_many :through on Opinion

```
@opinions = current_user.opinions # pulls in all of the user's opinions, which include respective resource ids
```

1. Calling for resource_id directly does not hit the database:

```
@opinions.each do |opinion|
  opinion.resource_id  # does not hit the database (as expected)
end
```

2. Performing a query does hit the database (even though variable has been assigned):

```
@opinions.find_by_resource_id(1) # DOES hit the database
```

Why does #2 hit the database?  Is there a way to perform the same find without hitting the database?

The information is already contained in the @opinions variable, so a db call does not seem necessary.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do in #2? Are you trying to extract the opinion in that collection with the specific id?

Comment: jstim: yes, that's what I want to do. I'm looping through a subset of the Resource model and want to display the user's opinion for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need anything else in the `@opinions` array, I would scope your original query to only include opinions with that `resource_id`

```
@opinions = current_user.opinions.where("resource_id = ?", resource_id)
```

If you already have `@opinions` and just want to create a new array of objects that match for a specific key/value:

```
@opinions_with_resource_id = @opinions.select { |opinion| opinion.resource_id == 1234 }
```

Check out [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069993/rails-filtering-array-of-objects-by-attribute-value) for another explanation or if you want to split the answer into multiple arrays.

### Thoughts

***Comment on your last piece of code***

Methods like you called `find_by_*` are dynamic finders that use `method_missing` to hit the database and look inside of the column specified by the *.

***Remaining comments from previous answer***

If this object will ever need to access data on the Resource model, don't forget about the `#includes()` method, which will keep you from having to run additional queries down the road.

```
@opinions = current_user.opinions.includes(:resources)
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: "All #1 is doing is pulling the array of Opinions, which contains the foreign_key to Resources that haven't been loaded yet." <-- The array of Opinions has all the information I need, which is the complete set of information for each Opinion (not just foreign_key as you mentioned).  Also I am not trying to load any Resource objects; I am trying to find Opinions that have a given resource_id.

Comment: ah ok, so say a user has 5 Opinions and 3 of them have resource_id equal to 124. You would like the query to pull back the 3 opinions with that value.

Comment: I have 1 user with several favorite resources, and I want to find the single opinion (which includes commentary, whether it is a favorite, etc) for each resource.  I already have all of the user's opinions in the @opinions variable, and I just want to pull information from this variable without hitting the database.

Comment: isn't the `include` method meant to be plural: `includes`?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon yup, I think you're right. updated.