# Is it better to use select or loop through an array of records in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, loops, select

My goal is to write the query below in the cleanest, most efficient way possible and minimize hitting the DB. Appreciate any guidance in advance.

I have retrieved some records that belong to a `user`, like below:

```rb
english_shows = @user.shows.where(language: 'english')
```

Let's say the `shows` belong to different `categories` (using a foreign key), so it looks like below:

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [
  <Show id: 1, category_id: 1, title: 'Rick and Morty'>,
  <Show id: 2, category_id: 2, title: 'Black Mirror'>,
  <Show id: 3, category_id: 3, title: 'Stranger Things'>,
  <Show id: 4, category_id: 3, title: 'Game of Thrones'>,
  ...
]
```

If I want to get the titles of the `shows` for each category, I know I can use `select` like this. <s>The same thing can be done with `where`, but this would cause an additional DB call.</s> (**[Edit]** Actually, both would hit the DB twice).

```rb
# Using select
cartoons = english_shows.select { |show| show.category_id == Category.find_by(name: 'cartoon').id}.pluck(:title)

# Using where
cartoons = english_shows.where(category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'cartoon').id)pluck(:title)
```

However, the `select` method would still result in multiple lines of long code (in my actual use case I have more category types). Is it cleaner to loop through the records like this (taken from this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10072413/11249670))?

```rb
cartoons, science_fiction, fantasy = [], [], []
@cartoon_id = Category.find_by(name: 'cartoon')
@science_fiction_id = Category.find_by(name: 'cartoon')
@fantasy_id = Category.find_by(name: 'cartoon')

english_shows.each do |show|
  cartoons << show if show.category_id == @cartoon_id
  science_fiction << show if show.category_id == @science_fiction_id
  fantasy << show if show.category_id == @fantasy_id
end
```

Comment: _"This would only hit the DB once"_ – where does `select` get the records from? Is `english_shows` already an array or a relation?

Comment: I guess this understanding was misguided - when I tried earlier, it seemed like `select` just used what was in the variable, but trying it just now I realised it still hits the DB to get the value of `english_shows` again. In that case, my question still stands - is it better to loop through, use `select`, or use `where`?

Comment: where will generally result in a far quicker execution - select will iterate through each record in the collection and apply the conditional to it - where will perform all of these operations in one transaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
english_shows
  .joins(:category)
  .select('shows.*, categories.name as category')
  .group_by(&:category)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and I could see that it was one DB call. Thank you!